# Why text () and style. width is not working in Js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a HTML like the below,

```
<div id ="b1>
     <i class="icon-clock"></i> <span class="font-weight-bold font-size-lg" id="currentTime"></span>
</div>
```

I could not get the `current date and time` displayed in the **particular Div**.

Js:

```
 // To display Date and time
    
    var target = document.getElementById('b1');
    var today = new Date();

    var date =
      today.getFullYear() +
      "-" +
      (today.getMonth() + 1) +
      "-" +
      today.getDate();

    var time =
      today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();

    var dateTime = date + " " + time;

   $(target).find('#currentTime').text(dateTime); // It dosen't displays the current date and time
```

And I need a solution about how to add the `Width` to the progress bar like the below,

```
<div id = "b2">
    <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar bg-success" id="div1" 
                style="width:0%">
           </div>
           <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" id="div2"
                style="width:0%">
           </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

If I use the below in the JS.

```
 var target = document.getElementById('b2');
 d1 = $(target).find('#div1');
 d2 = $(target).find('#div2');
 d1.style.width = 78 + "%";
 d2.style.width = 22 + "%";
```

I could get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'width')`.

Couldn't get the width for the progressbar. How to add the **Width** to the progress bar inside the particular div?

How to add the `Current Date and time` to the particular Id ?

Could anyone please help?

Many thanks.

Comment: Please make this an actual [mcve]

Comment: `d1` and `d2` are jQuery objects. These have no `.style` property. Either use the jQuery way ([jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)) or get a DOM node which has a `.style` property.

Comment: @Andreas, If I use $(d1).css(width,  78) // Is that correct? and to how display the current time and date in the particular div. Could you please help? Thanks

Comment: Your "b1" is not closed in the first HTML code. Please check that and confirm what is not working

Comment: Also in future, ask only one question with one post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are assuming JQuery [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) returns a DOM element on which [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) property exists.
But in reality, it returns a jQuery Object.

You can use `.css()` jQuery  method to make the change.

```
d1.css( "width", "78%" );
```

Comment: If this does it, please use the greentick to accept the answer.

Comment: I hope the problem with text() is fixed.

Comment: Yes, It is fixed. @Tushar